# Reading the return value of a java script function with "evaluateJavaScript" from Qt

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, google-maps, qtwebkit

[image: This is my route planner widget implemented with Qt5 and WebKit]

**How to get a JavaScript function return value in C++?**

After a long time of *not* using JavaScript, I implemented a route planner with the Google maps API V3. I defined some functions to access the scripting part of it via Qt's WebKit function: **evaluateJavaScript()**. Now the hard part is, to get the position data of the markers (see picture, markers are red). In the JavaScript end, I just return an array. How can I read the "latlng"-array in the Qt end?

**Illustration - This is what I want simplified:**

```
// JavaScript
function getJSFoo() {
  return foofoo;
}
// C++
void readInQt() {
  // something like this:
  float val = evaluateJavaScript("getJSFoo()");
  // Do stuff
}
```

Thanks in advance!

**This my code, more or less how I use it.
At JavaScript's end:**

```
// Add a marker to the map and push to the array.
function addMarker(location) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map,
      draggable:true
  });
  
  var LatLng = marker.getPosition();
  var sLatLng = "Latitude:    " + marker.getPosition().lat().toString() + 
                "\nLongitude: " + marker.getPosition().lng().toString();
  marker.setTitle(sLatLng);

  flightMarker.push(marker);
  return flightMarker;
}

function getMarkers() {
  var latlng = []
  for (var i = 0; i < flightMarker.length; i++) {
    latlng.push(flightMarker[i].getPosition() );
  }
  return latlng;
}
```

**At Qt's end:**

```
void sl_submitRoute() {
    getWaypoints();
}

QList<float> getWaypoints() {
    QList<float> lWaypoints;
    // I don't know what I do here :D
    QVariant varMarkers = mView->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript(QString("getMarkers();") );
    QList <QVariant> allListObj = varMarkers.toList();
    qDebug() << allListObj;

    return lWaypoints;
}
```

Comment: I don't know much about QML and I need the output for other reasons than just QML typical rendering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. Easiest way is to convert data into a QStringList and back. 
Otherwise data type conversion could result in a leak.

JavaScript

```
function getMarkers() {
  var latlng = []
  for (var i = 0; i < flightMarker.length; i++) {
    var sPos = flightMarker[i].getPosition().lat().toString() + ":" + flightMarker[i].getPosition().lng().toString();
    latlng.push(sPos);
  }
  return latlng;
}
```

Qt

```
// Returns a list of points: Latitude & Longitude
RouteF getWaypoints() {
    RouteF lWaypoints;

    QVariant varMarkers = mView->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript(QString("getMarkers();") );
    QList<QVariant> allListObj = varMarkers.toList();
    for(int i = 0; i < allListObj.size(); i++) {
        QStringList lPoint = allListObj.at(i).toString().split(':');
        if(lPoint.size() != 2) {
            qDebug() << "Warning: Waypoint not valid!";
            continue;
        }

        double fLat = lPoint.at(0).toDouble();
        double fLon = lPoint.at(1).toDouble();
        PointF waypoint = PointF(fLat, fLon);
        lWaypoints.push_back(waypoint);
        qDebug() << "Added point: " << fLat << ":" << fLon;
    }

    return lWaypoints;
}
```

Comment: Hello, I would like to do something similar in a small project, but I don't know where to start and I think I lake some knowledge as I couldn't know what to do just form what you provided. 
So Would you please provide me with a simple full working example so I can understand the whole thing. 
Thank you.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/rpicopter/ 
Look at the code of the GroundControl part.